# How can I segment data in R to include only points for which one of my variables is set to a specific value?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm working with a data set that has 16 variables and more than 4,000 cases. I'd like to segment the data into a separate data frame that only includes cases for which one of the variables is set to 0.

If I'm unclear, here's a simple example that, hopefully, will help illustrate my question:
Ana = red, 1
Beth = blue, 0
Cate = green, 3
David = yellow, 0

How would I, through R, segment the data set to create a new data frame that omits the cases for which the second variable = 0? In this example, I would have a new data frame that only includes Ana and Cate. Likewise, how would I do the opposite, i.e. create a data frame with only Beth and David?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume this is your `data.frame`

```
m <- data.frame(names = c("Ana", "Beth", "Cate", "David"), 
  colors = c("blue", "blue", "green", "yellow"), numbers = c(1, 0, 3, 0))
m
#  names colors numbers
#1   Ana   blue       1
#2  Beth   blue       0
#3  Cate  green       3
#4 David yellow       0
```

If I understood correctly here are two ways to obtain your result

```
id <- which(m[,"numbers"] > 0)
m[id,]
#1   Ana   blue       1
#3  Cate  green       3
```

or

```
subset(m, numbers > 0)
#  names colors numbers
#1   Ana   blue       1
#3  Cate  green       3
subset(m, numbers == 0)
#  names colors numbers
#2  Beth   blue       0
#4 David yellow       0
```

Comment: Or `m[m$numbers > 0,]`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use `split`, which would return a `list` of two `data.frame`s, one for the rows where `numbers == 0` and those where "numbers > 0". A trick to use is in how R treats numbers when you convert them to logical values: anything that is not zero becomes `TRUE`.

So, using @javlacalle's sample data, try:

```
out <- split(m, as.logical(m$numbers))
out
# $`FALSE`
#   names colors numbers
# 2  Beth   blue       0
# 4 David yellow       0
# 
# $`TRUE`
#   names colors numbers
# 1   Ana   blue       1
# 3  Cate  green       3
```

You can access the relevant `data.frame`s by their index position or their names:

```
out[[1]]
#   names colors numbers
# 2  Beth   blue       0
# 4 David yellow       0
out[["FALSE"]]
#   names colors numbers
# 2  Beth   blue       0
# 4 David yellow       0
```